# How to hide a widget with if an if condition in Flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is what I have so far:
This code returns the correct `isShow` values. If the value from `Firebase` is `yes` it returns `isShow` with true and if the value from `Firebase` is something other than `yes` it returns `isShow` with false.
So it seems to work when I try it, but after a while the `Button` hide/show at random, but the values are still correct.

So I think I am on the right track, just missing something.

Code:

```
bool isShow = true;

  updateToolDialog(BuildContext context, id) async {

    return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(id).get().then((querySnapshot) {

        statusservice = querySnapshot.get('status').toString();

          setState((){
          if(statusservice.contains('yes')) {
            isShow = true;
            print("should be true $isShow");
           
          }else{
            isShow = false;
            print("should be false $isShow");
            
          }});

      });
      return Dialog(
          child: Container(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 600,
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Text('Endre verktøy', style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                   
                    Visibility(
                      visible: isShow,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async{


                          FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

                          await firebaseFirestore.collection('users').doc(id).update({

                            'Status' : 'No',

                          });

                          Navigator.pop(context, true);
                          _initializeData();
                        },

                        child: const Text('Change status'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]
              ),
            ),
          ));
    });
  }
```

Comment: print the value of * value.docs* and let me know the value of it

Comment: This is the print `[Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot']`

Comment: add and await before value.docs and print it

Comment: Hi, where should I add await?

Comment: print("testing ${await value.docs }")

Comment: Still the same result: `testing [Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot']`.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do Like This

```
if(isSize.width ==100) {
SizedBox(width: 20, height: 100),
}else if(isSize.width ==50) {
SizedBox(width: 20, height: 50),
}
else {
SizedBox(width: 20, height: 20),
}
```

Replace Your Widgets where SizeBox Declare.

Comment: But how can I use this if I want to use my `Firebase` value as reference?